# What alternative should I look for JSON as my hosting MySQL 'yet' doesn't support JSON column type

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have been developing an application in my localhost for the past few weeks which relies heavily on JSON data type. Like I have a bunch of objects with numerous properties and I save those properties as JSON values in my `JSON` column of the database table.

But when I have moved from my localhost to my hosting at [hostgator](http://hostgator.com/), I've found that they are still using `libmysql - 5.1.73` which doesn't support `JSON` column (I really should have noticed it earlier).

My applications worked like this:

1. I create an object with multiple properties (>50 different properties).
2. I save the object in the database inserting object name in one column and all the properties as JSON in the other column.
3. I retrieve, update or delete the properties or the object.

In short I perform CRUD operation but as I have lots of properties for an object I used to keep them as JSON.

I'm not a professional, so I'd very much like some suggestions what possible solutions I should come up with in the coding side (other than rewriting everything/ changing the hosting). Or other approach I may take to save such amount of different properties for an object in my database? Thanks in advance for your suggestion.
(And say, I change the hosting. But even then, I'd like to learn the alternatives.)

Comment: Use a hosting provider that offers up-to-date software?

Comment: Yeah, MySQL 5.1 was released in 2008 and was end-of-lifed four years ago. You definitely want a host that takes security more seriously.

Comment: That would be my first choice but for some (complicated) reason, I can't use a different hosting right now. Thanks. @AlexHowansky

Comment: If they're using a version of MySQL that old, I'd wager the PHP version is probably similarly old, and probably unsupported with security patches, so using it is probably outright dangerous.

Comment: You can't use *this* hosting. It's dangerous.

Comment: If hosting costs are an issue then you can probably use Heroku or Amazon's free tier. Either is better than what you have.

Comment: Say, I change the hosting. But even then, I'd like to know the alternatives. I'd like to learn them too as I progress.

Comment: If your data is not relational (i.e. no relationships _between_ objects) then a NoSQL database might be the right fit for you